# Google Map Dynamically add pin and move?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to dynamically mark with push pin points on more than one place on Google maps.  It will be able drag to any place which is touched.  How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information in your question.  It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use this sample [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/)